# How to send to a specific signalr client in web api controller?

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, webapi, .net-6.0

I want to send data to a specific client. I have Asp.net core web api(.Net-6.0) controller which has a Hub help to call methods on remote Worker service. Hub is actively send call to a specific Worker clients one by one. **How and where can I keep connectionId and corresponding WorkerID** so that whenever MiniAppController get a request, it will use the hubContext fire the request through the right connection. The code example are:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    private readonly ILogger<ChatHub> _logger;
    public ChatHub(ILogger<ChatHub> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task HandShake(string workerId, string message)
    {
        HubCallerContext context = this.Context;
        await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("HandShake", workerId, context.ConnectionId);
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");

        await base.OnConnectedAsync();
    }
    public override async Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
    {
        await Groups.RemoveFromGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");
        _logger.LogInformation($"1.Server: Client disconnected  and left the group..............");
        await base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
    }
}
```

Webapi controller:

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class MiniAppController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<ChatHub> _chatHubContext;
    private readonly ILogger<ChatHub> _logger;

    public MiniAppController(IHubContext<ChatHub> chatHubContext)
    {
        _chatHubContext = chatHubContext;
    }
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<CheckoutInfo>> Checkout(string comID, string parkServerID, string parkLotID, string parkID, string miniAppID, string miniUserID, string sign)
    {
        string workerId = comID + parkServerID + parkLotID;//extracted from the method arguments
        ***//how to use workerId to send to a specific client???***
        ......
    }
}
```

Worker service as SignalR clients, I could have multiple workers:

```
    public class Worker1 : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker1> _logger;
    private HubConnection _connection;

    public Worker1(ILogger<Worker1> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
            .WithUrl("http://localhost:5106/chatHub")
            .WithAutomaticReconnect()
            .Build();

        _connection.On<string, string>("HandShakeAck", HandShakeAck);
        _connection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", ReceiveMessage);
        _connection.On<CheckoutRequest>("Checkout", Checkout);
    }
    public Task Checkout(CheckoutRequest checkoutRequest)
    {
        //send Checkoutinfo back
        CheckoutInfo checkoutInfo = new CheckoutInfo();
        _connection.InvokeAsync("ReceiveCheckoutInfo", workerId, checkoutInfo);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Check out my answer to a similar question. I believe it is what you are in need of. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71217523/14717905

Comment: Yes, I've been thinking of doing this like in your answer to that post. The problem is that  HubConnectionBuilder() and OnConnectedAsync() don't have arguments  which can be used to  send workerId to server when connection is established. I could start to build the mappings between the workerId and connectionId with calling HandSake(). but dont feel that is a good way. Is there a better way to do this?(like do it during the process of client making connections)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the best way to do this is to keep track of the connections in signalR groups. Each time a connection is made, we need to group it by the workerId that made the connection. It is ideal to do this in the onConnectedAsync method, because that way we wont have to do it manually everytime a connection is reset.

But how do we know which worker is connecting in the onConnectedAsync method? The same way I know in my application which user is connecting, by using an access token.

One thing to mention though, is that when using this access token, SignalR will put it as a query parameter when connecting using websockets. You may or may not desire this if you have IIS logging your active connections and you consider the worker id sensitive.
(When making use of long polling or SSE, the access token will be sent in the header of the request).

##### As such:

You could pass the worker id as the access token when starting the connection.

```
    _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl("http://localhost:5106/chatHub", options =>
         { 
            options.AccessTokenProvider = () => // pass worker id here;
         })
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();
```

Note: You could optionally encrypt the worker id and decrypt it server side.

If you didn't want to associate the workerId with the access token, then you could pass it as a hard coded query parameter too. (Doing this will keep it as a query parameter for all 3 types of signalR connections though).

```
    _connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
        .WithUrl($"http://localhost:5106/chatHub?workerId={workerId}")
        .WithAutomaticReconnect()
        .Build();
```

You could also use fully fledged JWT tokens, and embed the workerId in the JWT token too if you would like.

The next step would then be to get this worker id in the onConnectedAsync method. To do this we will need:

- workerId middleware (get the workerId)
- workerId Service (store and access the workerId)
- workerId requirements attribute (enforce the presence of a workerId for certain hub methods)
- WorkerId middleware result handler (what must happen if the workerId requirement fails)

###### The WorkerIdMiddleware can get the worker id for each request and store it in the request context:

*WorkerIdMiddleware.cs*

```
public class WorkerIdMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public WorkerIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        var workerId = httpContext.Request.Query["access_token"];

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(workerId))
        {
            AttachWorkerIdToContext(httpContext, workerId);
        }

        await _next(httpContext);
    }

    private void AttachWorkerIdToContext(HttpContext httpContext, string workerId)
    {
        if (ValidWorkerId(workerId))
        {
            httpContext.Items["WorkerId"] = workerId;
        }
    }

    private bool ValidWorkerId(string workerId)
    {
        // Validate the worker id if you need to
    }
}
```

###### We can then access the workerId via the WorkerIdService:

*WorkerIdService.cs*

```
public class WorkerIdService
{
    private string _currentWorkerId;
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public WorkerIdService(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        _currentWorkerId = GetCurrentWorkerIdFromHttpContext();
    }

    public string CurrentWorkerId
    {
        get
        {
            if (_currentWorkerId == null)
            {
                _currentWorkerId = GetCurrentWorkerIdFromHttpContext();
            }

            return _currentWorkerId;
        }
    }


    private string GetCurrentWorkerIdFromHttpContext()
    {
        return (string)_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext?.Items?["WorkerId"];
    }
}
```

###### The workerId requirement and requirement handler will allow us to protect our signalR methods and make sure a worker id is passed when we need it:

*ChatHubWorkerIdRequirement.cs*

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;

public class ChatHubWorkerIdRequirement : IAuthorizationRequirement
{
}
```

*ChatHubWorkerIdHandler.cs*

```
public class ChatHubWorkerIdHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ChatHubWorkerIdRequirement>
{
    readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public ChatHubWorkerIdHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }
    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext context, ChatHubWorkerIdRequirement requirement)
    {
        var workerId = (string)_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Items["WorkerId"];

        if (workerId != null)
        {
            // Connection may proceed successfully
            context.Succeed(requirement);
        }

        // Return completed task  
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

###### In order to customize the status code of the response when the workerId requirement fails, we can use an AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler

*HubWorkerIdResponseHandler.cs*

```
public class HubWorkerIdResponseHandler : IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler
{
    private readonly IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler _handler;

    public HubWorkerIdResponseHandler()
    {
        _handler = new AuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler();
    }

    public async Task HandleAsync(
        RequestDelegate requestDelegate,
        HttpContext httpContext,
        AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy,
        PolicyAuthorizationResult policyAuthorizationResult)
    {
        if (IsFailedPolicy(policyAuthorizationResult) && IsHubWorkerIdPolicy(authorizationPolicy))
        {
            // return whatever status code you wish if the hub is connected to without a worker id
            httpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            return;
        }

        await _handler.HandleAsync(requestDelegate, httpContext, authorizationPolicy, policyAuthorizationResult);
    }

    private static bool IsFailedPolicy(PolicyAuthorizationResult policyAuthorizationResult)
    {
        return !policyAuthorizationResult.Succeeded;
    }

    private static bool IsHubWorkerIdPolicy(AuthorizationPolicy authorizationPolicy)
    {
        return authorizationPolicy.Requirements.OfType<ChatHubWorkerIdRequirement>().Any();
    }
}
```

###### LASTLY You need to register everything in your startup like this:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    { 
        ...
        // Add the workerId policy
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationHandler, ChatHubWorkerIdHandler>();
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("WorkerIdPolicy", policy =>
            {
                policy.Requirements.Add(new ChatHubWorkerIdRequirement());
            });
        });

        // Hub Policy failure response handler (this will handle the failed requirement above)
        services.AddSingleton<IAuthorizationMiddlewareResultHandler, HubWorkerIdResponseHandler>();

        services.AddSignalR();

        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

        services.AddScoped<IWorkerIdService, WorkerIdService>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
       ...
       app.UseMiddleware<JwtMiddleware>();
       app.UseAuthorization();
       app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
          ...
          endpoints.MapHub<ChatHub>("ChatHub"); 
      );
       ...
    }
```

###### You can now decorate your ChatHub with the new authorization policy attribute we created. By decorating the entire hub class, the policy will be evaluated during the onConnectedAsync method.

(If you want the policy to fire on a method basis, you will need to decorate each individual method with the workerId policy attribute)

```
[Authorize(Policy = "WorkerIdPolicy")]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    ....
}
```

###### You can then access the CurrentWorkerId from the WorkerIdService during the onConnectedAsync method:

```
public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
{
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, "SignalR Users");
    // group the connections by workerId
    await Groups.AddToGroupAsync(Context.ConnectionId, $"Worker-{_workerIdService.CurrentWorkerId}");
    await base.OnConnectedAsync();
}
```

With this all in place, you will be able to send a signal to this worker group using a workerId, and know that only the client/s with that workerId will receive it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!    Really appreciated! Don't how to fix the error:
System.AggregateException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.IAuthorizationService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: Microsofte ...'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHttpContextAccessor'

Comment: How can I show you the full error message with stacktrace?

Comment: @Walker66 You need to call services.AddHttpContextAccessor(); from the ConfigureServices method in the Startup class. I accidentally forgot to add it, but have updated the answer now. I think this should solve the error.

Comment: @Walker66 If you still receive errors, perhaps we can create a chat room to converse further?

Comment: Thanks again. Yes, made some  progress, still have some errors. Realy sorry that I can't create a chat room now. I definitely will when it's convenient for you.  Talk to you in chat room tomorrow

Comment: It is working fine now. Thanks a lot! Whenever you have time, please join the chat room, I still have a question needs help.

Comment: I created a chat room for us to speak further. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242391/room-for-hedgybeats-and-walker66 If the answer worked for you please consider marking it as an accepted answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242392/discussion-between-walker66-and-hedgybeats).

Comment: Chat room loading forever...

Comment: @Walker66 That's weird, I can get in fine. Honestly to avoid any further hassles it might just be easier to email me. You can find my email in my profile.